# How can I run a selenium web scraping loop in Discord.py such that it doesn't block the use of commands while running?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, discord.py

I have a discord bot with some basic commands that I'm just using for testing purposes. One of the functions that I've implemented is a discord.py task which runs every X seconds. This task loops a function from another python file which uses Selenium and Beautiful soup to scrape twitter searches. The problem I've encountered is that when the scraper is running, it means no commands can be used through the bot. After the scraper is done running, the commands work as intended, but while the other file is sleeping to load the webpage, they don't work.

discordbot.py file

```
import discord
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext import tasks
from discord import app_commands
import threading
import time
from time import sleep
from twitterscrapper import scrapeSearch

searchInterval = 30
searchChannelID = 0000000

BOT_TOKEN = "TOKEN"
CHANNEL_ID = 000000

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.presences = True
intents.members = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
tree = app_commands.CommandTree(client)

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot Online")
    channel = bot.get_channel(CHANNEL_ID)
    await channel.send("Hello! Bot is online")
    try:
        synced = await bot.tree.sync()  # globally sync slash commands
        print(f"Synced {len(synced)} commands")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    scrapingLoop.start()


@bot.tree.command(name="ping", description="pong")
async def ping(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message("Pong!", ephemeral=True)


@bot.tree.command(name="memberinfo", description="Displays User Info")
async def memberinfo(interaction: discord.Interaction, member: discord.Member = None):
    if member == None:
        member = interaction.user
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Member Info")
    embed.add_field(name="ID", value=member.id)
    embed.add_field(name="Name", value=member.name)
    embed.add_field(name="Status", value=interaction.guild.get_member(member.id).status)
    embed.add_field(name="Creation Date", value=member.created_at.strftime("%m/%d/%Y"))
    await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed)

@tasks.loop(seconds=searchInterval)
async def scrapingLoop():
    print("running loop")
    link = scrapeSearch()
    if link != "No new posts":
        searchChannel = bot.get_channel(searchChannelID)
        await searchChannel.send(str(link))
    else:
        searchChannel = bot.get_channel(searchChannelID)
        await searchChannel.send(
            "No new posts found in the last " + str(searchInterval) + " seconds"
        )

bot.run(BOT_TOKEN)
```

twitterscraper.py file

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from urllib.parse import unquote
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions, Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import time
from time import sleep

target_url = "TWITTER SEARCH URL"


def scrapeSearch():
    options = ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

    driver.get(target_url)

    username = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located(
            (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[autocomplete="username"]')
        )
    )
    username.send_keys("PHONE_NUMBER")
    username.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

    password = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[name="password"]'))
    )
    password.send_keys("PASSWORD")
    password.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

    time.sleep(4)

    resp = driver.page_source

    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp, "html.parser")

    first_result = soup.find("article", {"data-testid": "tweet"})
    first_result_anchor_children = first_result.findChildren(name="a")

    for child in first_result_anchor_children:
        link = child.get("href")
        if "status" in link:
            link = "https://twitter.com" + link
            f = open("recentlink.txt", "r")
            lastLink = f.read()
            if lastLink == link:
                driver.close()
                print("1")
                link = "No new posts"
                return link
            else:
                f = open("recentlink.txt", "w")
                f.write(link)
                print("2")
                driver.close()
                return link
            break

    print(link)
```

I've tried by running the function in a new thread using threading, but I suspect I did that incorrectly because the function still blocked commands from running. The scraping function itself utilizes sleep() to give time for the webpage to load, but I'm not sure of any alternatives that would work here. Honestly I'm pretty new to using python in general so I'm pretty stumped with how to move forward.

Comment: It's tricky to combine threading and `async`.  You might consider having a completely separate task running continuously to do your scraping, and store the most recent rsults in a file using JSON (or some similar data store).  Then, your bot doesn't have to wait -- it just pull the most recent results from file.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this simply by replacing your use of `time.sleep()` with `asyncio.sleep()` in your scrapping function.

When `time.sleep(4)` is called, it will block the entire execution of the bot and it will be put on hold, just frozen, doing nothing. But when you call `await asyncio.sleep(4)`, it will ask the event loop to run something else while your `await` statement finishes its execution. This way, your commands can be executed while your scrapping function is waiting.

> Note: you will need to define your `scrapeSearch()` function as asynchronous. That is, `async def scrapeSearch()` and call it using `await scrapeSearch()`.